# Why is the memory usage of a child (python multiprocessing) process so different when sharing a ctypes.Structure with a string vs. only a string?

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, shared-memory

The following code uses `multiprocessing`'s `Array` to share a large array of unicode strings across processes. If I use `c_wchar_p` as the type, the child process' memory usage is about one quarter of memory used in the parent process (the amount changes if I change the amount of entries in the Array).

However, if I use a `ctypes.Structure` with a single `c_wchar_p` field the child process' memory usage is constant and very low while the parent process' memory usage doubles.

```
import ctypes
import multiprocessing
import random
import resource
import time

a = None

class Record(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('value', ctypes.c_wchar_p)]
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s)' % (self.value,)

def child(i):
    while True:
        print "%ik memory used in child %i: %s" % (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1024, i, a[i])
        time.sleep(1)
        for j in xrange(len(a)):
            c = a[j]

def main():
    global a
    # uncomment this line and comment the next to switch
    #a = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_wchar_p, [u'unicode %r!' % i for i in xrange(1000000)], lock=False)
    a = multiprocessing.Array(Record, [Record(u'unicode %r!' % i) for i in xrange(1000000)], lock=False)
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child, args=(i + 1,))
        p.start()
    while True:
        print "%ik memory used in parent: %s" % (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1024, a[0])
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using c_wchar_p results in this output:

```
363224k memory used in parent: unicode 0!
72560k memory used in child 5: unicode 5!
72556k memory used in child 3: unicode 3!
72536k memory used in child 1: unicode 1!
72568k memory used in child 4: unicode 4!
72576k memory used in child 2: unicode 2!
```

Using Record results in this output:

```
712508k memory used in parent: (unicode 0!)
1912k memory used in child 1: (unicode 1!)
1908k memory used in child 2: (unicode 2!)
1904k memory used in child 5: (unicode 5!)
1904k memory used in child 4: (unicode 4!)
1908k memory used in child 3: (unicode 3!)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the increase in memory usage but I don't think it is really doing what you intend to do.

If you modify `a[i]` in your parent process, the child processes don't get the same value.

It's best not to pass pointers (which is exactly what the `_p` types are) between processes. As quoted from `multiprocessing` docs:

> Although it is possible to store a pointer in shared memory remember that this will refer to a location in the address space of a specific process. However, the pointer is quite likely to be invalid in the context of a second process and trying to dereference the pointer from the second process may cause a crash.

Comment: And strangely, it does work, at least in my test, and the Python object appears to use lots more memory in the parent and lots less memory in the children. It would still be interesting to know the answer to this question.